# Mostrar un array de 0s y 1s en forma de matriz

Tags: javascript, array, binario

Me está costando terminar mi código, la idea es que los 1s y 0s se intercambien y eso lo he logrado, solo que además quiero representarlos en una matriz tal cual están en la variable arrayBinario (4 filas x 8 columnas) y no lo consigo. Cualquier sugerencia se agradece!

Código:

```
let arrayBinario = [
  1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1,
  1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1,
  1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0
]

function mostrarVector(vector) {

  for (let i = 0; i < (vector.length); i++) {
    if (arrayBinario[i] / 1 == 0) {
      arrayBinario[i] = 1;
    } else {
      arrayBinario[i] = 0;
    }
    console.log(vector[i]);
  }

  let grilla = vector.length * vector[0].length;

  for (let i = 0; i < vector.length; i++) {

    for (let j = 0; j < vector[i].length; j++) {
      console.log(vector[i][j] + " ");
    }
    console.log("\n");
  }
}

mostrarVector(arrayBinario);
```

Comment: No entiendo **donde** quieres mostrarlos con esa disposición.  ¿En el console.log?  ¿o bien en un formato HTML de salida?  Entiendo que seria con HTML pues el console.log hará lo que quiera con eso. De hecho lo más seguro es que la misma variable **arrayBinario** la mostrará así (en una linea): `[1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]`

Answer (score 0):

Supongo que lo te interesa es el algoritmo.

Lo primero es que console no te sirve, porque hace un salto de línea automático, así que yo voy a crear un textarea a modo de consola

```
<textarea id="Salida"></textarea>
```

## 1) Con un solo for

```
function mostrarVector(vector) {
  const Salida = document.getElementById("Salida");
  const cols = 8;
  
  for (let i = 0; i < vector.length; i++) {
      if ((i + 1) % cols != 0) {
          Salida.value += vector[i] + " ";
      }
      else {
          Salida.value += "\n";
      } 
  }
}
```

Ocupamos la función "resto entero" (%) para determinar cuándo hacer el salto de línea, es decir el truco está dentro del if

## 2) Ocupando 2 for

```
function mostrarVector2(vector){
   const Salida = document.getElementById("Salida");
  const cols = 8;
    const filas = vector.length /cols ;

    for (let i = 0; i < filas; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
           Salida.value += vector[i * cols + j] + " ";
        }
        Salida.value += "\n";
    }
}
```

En este caso el truco está en el índice del vector "i * cols + j"

Coméntame si necesitas más explicación

Answer (score 0):

Para declarar arrayBinario como array de 2 dimensiones (o matriz) deberias hacerlo asi:

```
let arrayBinario = [
    [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
    [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]
]
```

Porque como lo declaraste originalmente es un vector o array normal, solo esta tabulado para que parezca una matriz pero es un array unidimensional. Una vez hecho esto declaramos un array vacío que contendrá los números invertidos y la función que lo llenara

```
const arrayBinarioInvertido = []; // array vacío

arrayBinario.forEach (subarray => { // iteramos sobre cada subarray
  let auxarray = [] // array auxiliar que representa una fila de la matriz invertida que estamos buscando
  for(let i=0;i<subarray.length;i++){ // iteramos sobre cada posicion del subarray
    if(subarray[i]) auxarray.push(0) // si la posición del subarray contiene un 1, agregamos un 0 al array auxiliar y visceversa
    if(!subarray[i]) auxarray.push(1)
  }
  arrayBinarioInvertido.push(auxarray) // ahora agregamos el subarray a arrayBinarioInvertido
}) 

console.log(arrayBinario)
console.log(arrayBinarioInvertido)
```

Al final los arreglos bidimensionales son arrays dentro de otros arrays y podes pensarlo así. En la consola se muestra correctamente. Espero te sirva.